# Silent /t/ usage on short words?

Tags: phonology, silent-letters, fast-speech-rules

The censorship on Stackoverflow will kill the platform and it's elitist snakes will be haunted.

Consider following words,

- Its
- At
- That
- What

I often hear them as,

- I/?/s
- Aa
- Tha/?/
- Wha/?/

I'm interested to hear in which regional accents above pronunciations are used.

Comment: Well gosh...that would depend on where the speaker is from.

Comment: @Cascabel They were white just as I am, but I didn't ask the location.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. We deal with English from all over the world including America, England, Australia, India, etc. We don't ask _race_; however, we do entertain questions about  African-American dialect. Also, we  support  questions about regional dialects...

Comment: @Cascabel No. I need to know which regions pronounce the above words in such a way. I already omit /t/ on some of words that I pronounce.

Comment: @Cascabel In short, which accent pronounce them in that way?  Cockney?  New York?

Comment: @Cascabel Well, Looking at your location, it's acceptable that you can't answer it specifically.

Comment: These words are never pronounced alone. They always occur in constructions and contractions with other words, and they're never stressed. Naturally things will go missing, mostly consonants. The idea that there is really a /t/ that's usually pronounced is left over from grade school. Talk comes first, and writing limps a long way after.

Comment: @Cascabel I thought that way when you said, "I am sorry". Likewise, you made an assumption that I'm religious so you went ahead and used "My goodness".

Comment: @Cascabel, I think he assumes you said "my goodness" to avoid violating the 4th Commandment.

Comment: @Cascabel It might have to do something with Snake ;)

Comment: I am not just  an elitist  snake. I am a rattler, the jingle bells on a reindeer, a baby rattle, and the bell you try to hang on the cat...if you can.

Comment: @Cascabel I found where exactly that words pronounced that way, it's Southern California.

Answer (score 0):

Your ears heard them right. Many people speak those words that way. As pointed by @Cascabel in one of the comments, it's a matter of accent. For example, Americans often omit their T's but Indians like to keep them.

> Dropping T's in words like "kitten," "Vermont" and "important" is a
> normal speech pattern, and there's even a name for it:
> T-glottalization!

Reference: [www.quickanddirtytips.com](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/pronouncing-T#:%7E:text=The%20phenomenon%20itself%20is%20known,and%20%E2%80%9CWAH%2Der.%E2%80%9D)

Comment: I too omit /t/ on certain words, but I'm not sure about the words I listed above. I'm looking for a quick verification.

Comment: Cockney too word final but more like a glottal stop rather than the American unreleased stop.

Comment: @jeffbRTC What is it exactly you want verified? That other people do it at all? Or something else like which region do people come from that do it?

Comment: @Mitch I'm interested to know which region.

Comment: @jeffbRTC You may refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization

Comment: @Cascabel The countries are UK, Ireland, Scotland and the USA.

Comment: @poops...It is possible that this is a duplicate, as _[T-Glottalization](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21681/how-do-you-proceed-from-pronouncing-t-in-the-regular-way-to-t-glottalization)_ has been dealt with here on this site in  much  detail at least twice that I count. If you would like this answer to stand out, you might want to go into more detail i.e. in some places, such as urban areas, the accent is more pronounced. Just sayin'...

Comment: @Cascabel I am sure it's a duplicate. You can report it as one if you want to because the OP hasn't shown research efforts anyway. There are many wonderful articles on the internet too. I don't think I can capture all their essence in one answer plus I am not interested in pinpointing the latitude and longitudes of those regions.

Comment: It should also be noted that many people won't hear the "T", even though it's technically present, since their hearing "expectations" are "tuned" to a different dialect.

Comment: @PoopsAndGiggles The OP's examples are all word-final, but all your examples are word-medial (in the middle). While this may be a seemingly ignorable nuance, the two phenomena are distinct. Different things happen to those two in different regions/accents/registers. For some it's a glottal stop, for some it's a dental flap, for some it's dropped altogether, for some it's there like it has been for awhile.